# Replace the value of attribute data-image-src

Tags: java, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the value of attribute `data-image-src` which is used on a `div` tag like this:-

```
<div class="bg-image cover-bg"  id="mobile-app"  data-image-src="assets/img/slider-4.jpg" data-overlay="4"></div>
```

What I need is to change the value of `data-image-src` from "`assets/img/slider-4.jpg`" to "`assets/img/vs-app.jpg`" on click of a button which is made by `<a>` tag.

Comment: Show us what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get and set your data attribute like below.

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
  $('.bg-image').data('image-src', 'assets/img/vs-app.jpg');
  console.log($('.bg-image').data('image-src'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg-image cover-bg" id="mobile-app" data-image-src="assets/img/slider-4.jpg" data-overlay="4">1234</div>

<a href='#'>Click to change<a/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<a href='http://www.test.com' onclick='return change()'>change</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function change()
{
    //Change the value of data-image-src here
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) because of compatibility with IE. Details [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/when-to-use-attr-vs-data).

```js
$("#click").on("click", function() {
  $("#mobile-app").attr("data-image-src", "assets/img/vs-app.jpg");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg-image cover-bg"  id="mobile-app"  data-image-src="assets/img/slider-4.jpg" data-overlay="4"></div>
<a id="click" href="#">Click</a>
```